# A server is to a client, as to serve is to?

Tags: single-word-requests

A server serves a client. A client *???* a server?

It can be stated as: A client "gets served from" a server, but this is in terms of the server. What would it be in terms of the client's action and not that of the server's?

Comment: *be served*....

Comment: That's still in terms of the server. Is there something like cliented?

Comment: No, I don't think so. A client sends requests to a server and receives responses from that server. I know of no single word for that.

Comment: are you speaking technically like a web browser or software on a computer that interacts with data on a server?

Comment: Not necessarily... I mean a customer gets served by a server at a restaurant.

Comment: @Drew "A client sends requests to a server and receives responses". That's not necessarily true. A web socket or serial bus client receives, but does not necessarily send messages. A logging client only sends, but never receives.

Comment: @jimm101: Can send, can receive. Typically sends and receives. Whatever.

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking IT, the clients send requests to the server in most architectures. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Comment: A server provides resources, which the client consumes.

Comment: Ok, so a client sends requests to a server, but that is not in terms of the client. Just as we can say: a server serves, can we say: A client clients?

Comment: "Client" is not a verb, it's a noun or adjective.

Comment: Wudang gave you the answer, it's: REQUEST

Comment: @JohnFeltz, I think you should add "consume" as an answer.

Comment: A client can also "listen for responses"... and/or "recieve" responses

Answer (score 0):

I agree that *request* is more idiomatic in a client/server model. However, another suggestion is ***query***.

> :  to ask questions of especially with a desire for authoritative information
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/query)</sub>

This is used in computer jargon for client/server interactions, especially databases (SQL, one of the most common database languages, stands for *Structured Query Language*).

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest 'consume' but alwayslearning got there first.

Particularly if the diner in the restaurant is still on board, computers and customers both 'use' or 'control' their servers or 'consume' the services provided

'Request' is a step removed. Computer or customer both 'make requests of' a server or 'request the server for' something. Can either ever simply 'request' the server.

Similarly, 'order/direct/instruct.'